# XOR encryption attack vector

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, xor

Lets say the key is a string of length 10, perfectly random.
We use the key to xor a large quantity of perfectly random length 10 strings.
Can the key be recovered if the encrypted strings are compromised?

Comment: What do you mean by "encrypted strings are compromised"?  If an attacker has one ciphertext and one plaintext for that ciphertext, getting the key is a trivial xor.

Comment: @Roman: please be more clear what you mean with the words "string" and by "compromised". And guys, this is not a programming question and is better handled at [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

If the input data are **completely random**, then applying a **completely random** key via XOR doesn't produce any meaningful patterns. The result is still random, and no information can be gleaned from randomness.

The reason XOR isn't used as an encryption mechanism is generally known-plaintext attacks, which do not apply against a random corpus.

Comment: @Jean-BernardPellerin The asker said "perfectly random". That means "comprised of a sequence of ten bytes, each selected independently from the range [0,255], with no bias toward a particular value or set of values". "string" doesn't mean ASCII or text; "string" can mean "sequence of bytes".

Answer (score 4):

If two cyphertexts which use the same key are XOR'ed together then all key information is removed, and it is possible to recover information about the plaintexts.  If you plaintexts are random, then that will not be much, but some will be recoverable.  If the plaintexts are meaningful then a lot more information will be recoverable.

C1 = P1 XOR K

C2 = P2 XOR K

C1 XOR C2 = (P1 XOR K) XOR (P2 XOR K) = P1 XOR P2

That is why the One Time Pad must be a **One** Time Pad.  Using the same random key twice makes it breakable.  Google "Venona" for a real life example.

Answer (score 2):

Yes!

The strings might be random but they will still follow some form of character encoding (ascii, utf, ebcdic, etc...) and so only certain bytes will be valid.

An attacker can loop through possible keys discounting the ones that result in plaintext that is not valid ascii(or w/e). This can be done one key-character at a time and so it's not 26^10, but 26*10 (for a 26 character alphabet).

This is an unsafe encryption scheme.

Comment: good point, though the strings will be random byte streams (only later encoded in character encoding)

Comment: @Roman the fact that they're encodeable is enough to grant the weakness I outline

Comment: to be exact, both the key and the large set of strings are random byte streams, only later encoded to be stored in a database, will patterns still be present?

Comment: what data is not encodeable? it's just another way to represent it

Comment: If the byte stream represents characters then it has a pattern, even if they are random characters. If the individual bits are random then you're safe.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a one time pad, except for the fact that you said that the same key would be used for a large quantity of strings. Now the strings would also be perfectly random, but are their content known in unencrypted form?